# Formula to display time difference in minutes between 2 fields while excluding weekends

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime

I'm facing an issue with a formula, and I could use some support. I have a requirement to calculate the time difference in minutes between two datetime fields, `Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c` and `CreatedDate`. However, I need the calculation to exclude weekends (Saturday and Sunday).
I have tried a couple of formulas without success.

The formula was changed to count the weekend days using the below formula, and it’s working as expected. Then another field was created to calculate the time difference in minutes, but it does not work properly when more than 1 day is included in a response.

Here are a few examples:
Created date: Thursday 27.07 at 09h30
Response date: Monday 31.07 at 08h20
Thursday 9h30 = 590 minutes
Friday 1440 minutes
Monday 8h20 = 500 minutes
Total 2530
Sf formula shows 5690

Created date: Saturday 29.07 at 20h58
Response date: Monday 31.07 at 08h18
Monday 8h18 = 498 minutes
Sf formula shows 340

Formula to calculate the number of weekend days:

```
CASE(MOD( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1985,6,24),7),
0 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), 7),1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,1,6,2,0),
1 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), 7),0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,2,2),
2 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), 7),0,0,1,0,2,0,3,1,2),
3 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), 7),0,0,1,0,2,1,2),
4 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), 7),0,0,1,1,2),
5 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), 7),0,1,2),
6 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), 7),6,2,1),
999)
+
(FLOOR(( DATEVALUE(Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate))/7)*2)
```

Formula to calculate time difference in minutes: (does not work as expected)

```
CASE(
    MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),
    0, ((CreatedDate + 1) - Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c - (7 / 24)) * 1440,
    6, ((CreatedDate + 2) - Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c - (7 / 24)) * 1440,
    (Email_First_Reply_Date_Time__c - CreatedDate) * 1440
)
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could review the formula and provide guidance on how to correctly calculate the time difference in minutes while excluding weekends.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do the example formulas not cover this?  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

The below formula returns the minutes between two DateTime fields.
For example, LastModifiedDate is 5/30/2023, 11:00 PM and CreatedDate is  5/30/2023, 3:22 PM then the formula returns the 458 minutes. The formula also excludes the Weekends.

You can also verify using the [TimeDuration](https://www.calculator.net/time-duration-calculator.html) Calculator.

Formula:

```
TEXT(
        IF((ROUND((CASE(MOD( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 8),7), 
                        0 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
                        1 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
                        2 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
                        3 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
                        4 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
                        5 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
                        6 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
                        999) 
                        + 
                (FLOOR(( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) )/7)*5)) -1 
                + ((CreatedDate - CreatedDate) 
                + (LastModifiedDate - LastModifiedDate)),0) 
                * 24 * 60) = 0,
        IF(IF(ROUND(MOD((LastModifiedDate- CreatedDate)*24,24),0)=24,0,
              ROUND(MOD((LastModifiedDate- CreatedDate)*24,24) * 60 ,0) 
             ) = 0,
           IF(Round(MOD((LastModifiedDate- CreatedDate)*1440,60),0)=60,0,
              Round(MOD((LastModifiedDate - CreatedDate)*1440,60),0) 
             ),
             IF(ROUND(MOD((LastModifiedDate- CreatedDate)*24,24),0)=24,0,
                ROUND(MOD((LastModifiedDate- CreatedDate)*24,24) * 60 ,0) 
               )
        ),
        (ROUND((CASE(MOD( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 8),7), 
                     0 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
                     1 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
                     2 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
                     3 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
                     4 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
                     5 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
                     6 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
                     999) 
                     + 
                (FLOOR(( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) )/7)*5)) -1 
                + ((CreatedDate - CreatedDate) 
                + (LastModifiedDate - LastModifiedDate)),0) 
                * 24 * 60)
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tested this formula, and it looks like when the created date and the time of the first reply are on different days, I get a value of 1440. If they are two days apart, I get 2880. And if they are three days apart, I get 4320 and so on. The formula only works correctly when the two dates are on the same day.